# Inclusion filtering in postgresql on a enum type column

Tags: ruby, postgresql, dry-rb, rom-rb

I have a postgres enum `create_enum(:status_type, %i[requested approved])`. 
I created a column in a table with a `status_type :status, null: false`.

I am trying to filter with inclusion on it in ruby like this: `root.where(requests[:status].in(*values)`. `values` is an array of strings.

This code returns the following error:
`Dry::Types::ConstraintError: ["requested"] violates constraints (included_in?(["requested", "approved"], ["requested"]) failed)`.

If I filter by equality on it, it works ok. `root.where(requests[:status].is('requested')`

Do you know a way for me to filter with inclusion on a custom type column?

Comment: Whoever interested, track this issue https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-sql/issues/368